# How to create a multidimensional array with a random length of columns in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to create a multidimensional array in Java but with a random lenght of colums.

For example let's suppose the random lengths are 3, 2, 4 and 1, so we would have something like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [3]]
```

I have tried this, but it does not create a random length for each column:

```
int articles[][] = new int[50][(int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 30 + 1)];
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Note: The array will always have 50 rows, I just need each column to be random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to initialize your arrays in array, inside any loop, for example:

```java
int articles[][] = new int[50][];
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    articles[i] = new int[(int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 30 + 1)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I recommend you study the utility methods in `java.util.Arrays`. It is a goldmine of helper methods for working with arrays. Since 1.8 it has this one:

   ```java
   int articles[][] = new int[50][];
   Arrays.setAll(articles, i -> new int[(int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 30 + 1)]);
   ```

   Using a lambda is not more efficient than a plain loop in this problem case but often lends itself to neater overall solutions.
2. I would also recommend not scaling `double` to `int` yourself (see the source of `Random.nextInt()` and decide for yourself).

   ```java
   Random r = new Random();
   int articles[][] = new int[50][];
   Arrays.setAll(articles, i -> new int[r.nextInt(30)]);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To create an array with a constant count of rows, but a random row length, and fill it with random numbers:

```java
int rows = 5;
int[][] arr = IntStream
        .range(0, rows)
        .mapToObj(i -> IntStream
                .range(0, (int) (Math.random() * 10))
                .map(j -> (int) (Math.random() * 10))
                .toArray())
        .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

```java
// output
Arrays.stream(arr).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

```
[3, 8]
[2, 7, 6, 8, 4, 9, 3, 4, 9]
[5, 4]
[0, 2, 8, 3]
[]
```